# How to change default name of OpenID Connect middleware (nonce and correlation) cookies

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect

I'm using the two ASP.NET Core middlewares for OpenID Connect and cookie authentication like below:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "cookie",
    CookieName = "clientcookiename",
    CookieHttpOnly = true,
    CookieSecure = _hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest : CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = false,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)
});

var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
    SignInScheme = "cookie",                
    ...
};
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(oidcOptions);
```

During login in the web application this results in some default cookies related to nonce and correlation which look like this (exported from my browser developer tools):

```
{
    "domain": "localhost",
    "expirationDate": 1478762475.872038,
    "hostOnly": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": ".AspNetCore.OpenIdConnect.Nonce.CfDJ...ihRRfQid0Rw",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "N",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "domain": "localhost",
    "expirationDate": 1478762474.872093,
    "hostOnly": true,
    "httpOnly": true,
    "name": ".AspNetCore.Correlation.oidc.Apx...XlCFhuc...Hcq8",
    "path": "/",
    "sameSite": "no_restriction",
    "secure": false,
    "session": false,
    "storeId": "0",
    "value": "N",
    "id": 2
  }
```

1. What are the responsibility of these cookies?
2. How do we change the CookieName of these cookies?
3. Will changing CookieName of these cookies have any consequences in some other place?

Answer (score 4):

> What are the responsibility of these cookies?

The correlation and nonce cookies are respectively used to prevent XSRF/session fixation attacks and replay attacks. They are an essential part of the security checks used by the OpenID Connect middleware.

> How do we change the CookieName of these cookies?

You can't. In both cases, the cookie name is not configurable (it's prefixed by  hardcoded part).

The relevant code can be found here:

- Correlation cookie: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/RemoteAuthenticationHandler.cs#L198
- Nonce cookie: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectHandler.cs#L896

Comment: Thanks for your answer and +1 for also pointing to the source code. It sucks that we can't change the name of theses cookies, why hard code  this and expose that web applications is using ASP.NET Core?!

Comment: I presume it's as simple as "nobody asked for an option to configure that yet" :)

Answer (score 1):

This have been [implemented](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/pull/1284/files#diff-5f153b21e61d008634c479494de719d6)

`oidcOptions.NonceCookie = new CookieBuilder()
{
    Name = "TheNonceCookieName"
};`

Comment: It changes the prefix of the cookie name only. The rest of the cookie name remains random

Answer (score 1):

Just setting cookie name didn't work for Asp.Net Core 2.0. I had to set other properties as well:

```
// https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication/RemoteAuthenticationOptions.cs#L26
options.CorrelationCookie = new Http.CookieBuilder()
{
    Name = "my_correlation_cookie",
    HttpOnly = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
    Expiration = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)
};

// https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L71
options.NonceCookie = new Http.CookieBuilder()
{
    Name = "my_nonce_cookie",
    HttpOnly = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
    Expiration = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0)
};
```

Comment: Can we set the domain of these cookies too without requiring a new CookieBuilder? Eg options.CorrelationCookie.Domain = "mysite.com"

Comment: It changes the prefix of the cookie name only. The rest of the cookie name remains random